# Automatically locating endpoints (river sources) in a stream network

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, network, hydrology

I have a stream network in ArcGIS 10.2.2 and I would like to know if it is possible to automatically add endpoints based on the stream network.

[image: Stream network with identified river sources]

The network is pretty big and doing this manually would take too much time.

Comment: The Rivex extension for Arcmap (rivex.co.uk) has this functionality.

Comment: Summarise streams table by to node name. No match in nodes table are your sources.